# Two Sum Index List Out of Range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, nested-lists

I keep getting the error "list index out of range" on the problem "two sum" on leetcode, I know that there is a faster way to solve it using dict however, I am just starting leetcode and I would like to know why I am getting this error.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        i = 0
        j = i + 1
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(len(nums)):
                
                if i + j == target:
                    
                    return(nums[i], nums[j])
                
                else:
                    
                    i = i + 1
```

Comment: `i = i + 1` change the value of `i` so `nums[i]` may access `num[len(nums)]` which cause error. Try `print` the result of intermediate step to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing `i` in the `else` branch of your inner `j` loop. This is moving your `i` variable ahead at the same pace as the `j` in the inner loop. Therefore, when `i` in the outer loop is greater than zero you'll get an out of bounds error, assuming your indices are not summing to the target, as checked in your `if`.

There are several problems with the code as written, though.

- You set `j` to `i + 1` before you start your loops. That will be overwritten immediately on each start of the inner loop (as it will be defined by the `range` method call).
- You check `if i + j == target`, when you should be checking the value of the array at those indices, like `if nums[i] + nums[j] == target`.
- You are incrementing the `i` variable inside the inner `j` loop, without checking it in that loop. The `range` check will only verify that `i` is within the range bounds of the outer loop when the outer loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

if you delete the last two lines it works and these two lines 3 and 4 extra; so

```py
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(len(nums)):
                
                if i + j == target:
                    
                    return(nums[i], nums[j])
```

if i neads to be 1 number above j:

```py
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(1, len(nums) + 1):
                
                if i + j == target:
                    
                    return(nums[i], nums[j])
```